# Why do my routes fail after calling a destroy function?

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, routes

There have been a few iterations of this code but I will only show what has worked best so far (no errors).

Destroy Function:

```
public function destroy($locale, $id)
{
    Component::where('id', $id)->delete();

    $locale = App::getLocale();

    return route('components.index', compact('locale'));
}
```

Index Function (referenced above):

```
public function index($locale)
{
    parent::lang($locale);

    $components = Component::paginate(10);

    return view('production/index-component', compact('components'));
}
```

Relevant Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function() {
    Route::resource('/components', ComponentController::class);
});
```

[Resulting URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InY3U.png)

The destroy function works otherwise, records are deleted (upon going to the correct URL). Ideally this should simply redirect the user back to {locale}/components.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are returning a URL as a string, not a redirect response ... check the documentation for returning a redirect  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Comment: Wow, Thank you! I'm embarassed to say how long this has been plaguing me.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to lagbox,

```
public function destroy($locale, $id)
{

    Component::where('id', $id)->delete();

    $locale = App::getLocale();

    return redirect()->route('components.index', ['locale' => $locale]);
}
```

This worked perfectly.